# Create Music Slide show with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4

I am now trying to create picture slide show video with music. So far, I only know ffmpeg will be one of the solution. I successfully create one with my own picture and music. However, i wonder whether ffmpeg allows me to create such music slide show according to the beat of a song. What i mean all picture transition takes place at each beat of the song.

The photo slide show video should be in mp4 format.

Comment: `ffmpeg` does not have such a feature. You could perhaps use the [concat demuxer](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat) with the `duration` option for each frame, but I don't know how you could automate it (specifically, acquiring the timing values).

Comment: you might be able to figure out "beat" using the astats filter...